# Need help in FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I tried the query on FQL using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

The command I entered was `SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = me()`

But the data returned was limited to 100 entries only. Is there some kind of restriction on the amount of data entered? Is there a way to change this restriction?

Comment: Did you try using a larger limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify limit to the number of results returned.
The default is 100 as you can see. You should consider using larger limits.

Example: `SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = me() limit 200`;